# Не приходят письма от имени некоторых почт

Tags: php, email, umi

На сайте на umi cms при отправке пользователем формы формируется письмо которое должно приходить администратору от имени этого человека, то есть от имени почты который тот указал в форме
Но дело в том что от некоторых почт не приходят сообщения например от мейл ру вообще по нулям от гмаил все норм

Кто-нибудь знает что это такое?

Comment: спам фильтр какой-нить

Comment: зачем вообще отправлять сообщение от имени пользователя?

Comment: Возможно внутренний SMTP на хостинге полностью фильтрует mail.ru, так как это та еще спам-контора.